# How to disable keyboard to enter value input type number in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

How to restrict the user to do not use keyboard to enter number, only he have to choose from number panel where input field is number type?

Comment: Use `disabled` attribute.

Comment: Following your edit, your answer is still wrong. User can still paste some value or cut it (using his mouse e.g).

Answer (score -6, accepted):

```
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Input Text Number Disable</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="number" />
    <script>
    $('input').keypress(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't disable it or your definition for disable input is wrong...

Comment: ...and this affects *all* inputs on the page, not just number inputs.